# Using an array in a List - OOP - Generic List

Tags: c#, list, oop

I have created a list:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee();
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(Job.Employee, "Name", "C Sharp", "Oracle", "SQL");
```

I currently have this:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(Job.Employee, "Name", Skills.CSharp);
```

This is the code inside the `Employee` class

```
public enum Job { Employee, Supervisor, Administrator };
public enum Skills {CSharp, SQL, PHP, Javascript, Web, Python, Oracle, CPlus, Perl };

protected Job job;
protected String employeeName;
protected String employeeName;

public Job Job
{
    get { return job; }
    protected set { job = value; }
}

public String EmployeeName
{
    get { return employeeName; }
    protected set { employeeName = value; }
}

public Skills Skills
{
    get {return skills; } 
}
```

I want to be able to enter as many 'skills' as I want as currently, only one skill can be entered in the Employee e1 as I have used a enum.

How would I put an array of 'skills' in the list/constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) array parameter to pass variable number of `Skills` parameters to the constructor:

```
public Employee(Job job, string name, params Skills[] skills)
```

You will also have to modify the `skills` field to hold a collection of `Skills` instead of a single one. You can make it an array if you will not add/remove skills after the employee is created, or an `IList<Skills>` if you need to modify the collection.

For example:

```
public class Employee
{
    private List<Skills> _skills;       // skills stored as a private List 
                                        // to allow modification inside Employee class

    public Employee(Job job, string name, params Skills[] skills)
    {
        _skills = new List<Skills>(skills);
        ...
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Skills> Skills // publicly visible as a read-only list
    {
        get { return _skills.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: And change the member variable and property to be a collection type.

Comment: My constructor is this: 
`public Employee (Job Job, String Name, Skills Skills) { job = Job; name = Name; skills = Skills;}`

Comment: @Jakub could you add some more detail on what you mean by modifying the skills field? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @DannyWatson Sure. Check the edited answer for an example.

Comment: While I used the other persons answer in my code I believe your code was the most helpful and of course you put more effort into your solution for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to passing in a `Skills[]`, you can change your `enum` to be a bit-mask of the skills that an employee has:

```
[Flags]
enum Skills
{
   None = 0,
   CSharp = 1 << 0,
   SQL = 1 << 1,
   PHP = 1 << 2,
   Javascript = 1 << 3,
   ...
}
```

Then the individual skills can be bitwise ORed together to create the skills that an individual employee has:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(Job.Employee, "Name", Skills.CSharp | Skills.SQL | Skills.PHP );
```

Then to check if an employee has a specific skill, you can use [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, eg:

```
if( e1.Skills.HasFlag( Skills.CSharp ) )
```

Comment: Good solution, although it limits the number of skills to 32 (or 64 with `long` underlying type)